# dplyr grouped sum returning wrong value

Tags: r, dplyr, group-by, summarize

I incurred in a weird error I could not find a solution for. I already checked several related post here on stack overflow, but they are not really addressing the issue I am facing here.

I am trying to create grouped summation from logical vectors. The data are structured as follows:

For each unit of observation (country) I have a list of events, which are reported weekly. So, if I have 105 weeks (roughly 2 years), and supposing a country to have experienced 3 events, I have a dataframe with 315 observation (country-week-event).

I want to group and summarize the data at (country-week level). To stay with the previous figures, I want 105 observation for each country.
If I check the result of the summation however, I notice that an error returns, and a sum that shoulg return value 1 actually returns value 2. In particular, the summation of the column restriction should return 1 (as, for each week, I am summing up two "FALSE" statements and only one "TRUE" statement)

Any idea for why this might be happening? Other summations (like the facilitation one reported below) work fine

Below my data

```
data <- structure(list(ccode = c("AGO", "AGO", "AGO", "AGO", "AGO", "AGO", 
"AGO", "AGO", "AGO", "AGO", "AGO", "AGO", "AGO", "AGO", "AGO", 
"AGO", "AGO", "AGO", "AGO", "AGO", "AGO", "AGO", "AGO", "AGO", 
"AGO", "AGO", "AGO", "AGO", "AGO", "AGO", "AGO", "AGO", "AGO", 
"AGO", "AGO", "AGO", "AGO", "AGO", "AGO", "AGO", "AGO", "AGO", 
"AGO", "AGO", "AGO", "AGO", "AGO", "AGO", "AGO", "AGO", "AGO", 
"AGO", "AGO", "AGO", "AGO", "AGO", "AGO", "AGO", "AGO", "AGO", 
"AGO", "AGO", "AGO", "AGO", "AGO", "AGO", "AGO", "AGO", "AGO", 
"AGO", "AGO", "AGO", "AGO", "AGO", "AGO", "AGO", "AGO", "AGO", 
"AGO", "AGO", "AGO", "AGO", "AGO", "AGO", "AGO", "AGO", "AGO", 
"AGO", "AGO", "AGO", "AGO", "AGO", "AGO", "AGO", "AGO", "AGO", 
"AGO", "AGO", "AGO", "AGO", "AGO", "AGO", "AGO", "AGO", "AGO", 
"AGO", "AGO", "AGO", "AGO", "AGO", "AGO", "AGO", "AGO", "AGO", 
"AGO", "AGO", "AGO", "AGO", "AGO", "AGO", "AGO", "AGO", "AGO", 
"AGO", "AGO", "AGO", "AGO", "AGO", "AGO", "AGO", "AGO", "AGO", 
"AGO", "AGO", "AGO", "AGO", "AGO", "AGO", "AGO", "AGO", "AGO", 
"AGO", "AGO", "AGO", "AGO", "AGO", "AGO", "AGO", "AGO", "AGO", 
"AGO", "AGO", "AGO", "AGO", "AGO", "AGO", "AGO", "AGO", "AGO", 
"AGO", "AGO", "AGO", "AGO", "AGO", "AGO", "AGO", "AGO", "AGO", 
"AGO", "AGO", "AGO", "AGO", "AGO", "AGO", "AGO", "AGO", "AGO", 
"AGO", "AGO", "AGO", "AGO", "AGO", "AGO", "AGO", "AGO", "AGO", 
"AGO", "AGO", "AGO", "AGO", "AGO", "AGO", "AGO", "AGO", "AGO", 
"AGO", "AGO", "AGO", "AGO", "AGO", "AGO", "AGO", "AGO", "AGO", 
"AGO", "AGO", "AGO", "AGO", "AGO", "AGO", "AGO", "AGO", "AGO", 
"AGO", "AGO", "AGO", "AGO", "AGO", "AGO", "AGO", "AGO", "AGO", 
"AGO", "AGO", "AGO", "AGO", "AGO", "AGO", "AGO", "AGO", "AGO", 
"AGO", "AGO", "AGO", "AGO", "AGO", "AGO", "AGO", "AGO", "AGO", 
"AGO", "AGO", "AGO", "AGO", "AGO", "AGO", "AGO", "AGO", "AGO", 
"AGO", "AGO", "AGO", "AGO", "AGO", "AGO", "AGO", "AGO", "AGO", 
"AGO", "AGO", "AGO", "AGO", "AGO", "AGO", "AGO", "AGO", "AGO", 
"AGO", "AGO", "AGO", "AGO", "AGO", "AGO", "AGO", "AGO", "AGO", 
"AGO", "AGO", "AGO", "AGO", "AGO", "AGO", "AGO", "AGO", "AGO", 
"AGO", "AGO", "AGO", "AGO", "AGO", "AGO", "AGO", "AGO", "AGO", 
"AGO", "AGO", "AGO", "AGO", "AGO", "AGO", "AGO", "AGO", "AGO", 
"AGO", "AGO", "AGO", "AGO", "AGO", "AGO", "AGO", "AGO", "AGO", 
"AGO", "AGO", "AGO"), week = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 
9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 
22L, 23L, 24L, 25L, 26L, 27L, 28L, 29L, 30L, 31L, 32L, 33L, 34L, 
35L, 36L, 37L, 38L, 39L, 40L, 41L, 42L, 43L, 44L, 45L, 46L, 47L, 
48L, 49L, 50L, 51L, 52L, 53L, 54L, 55L, 56L, 57L, 58L, 59L, 60L, 
61L, 62L, 63L, 64L, 65L, 66L, 67L, 68L, 69L, 70L, 71L, 72L, 73L, 
74L, 75L, 76L, 77L, 78L, 79L, 80L, 81L, 82L, 83L, 84L, 85L, 86L, 
87L, 88L, 89L, 90L, 91L, 92L, 93L, 94L, 95L, 96L, 97L, 98L, 99L, 
100L, 101L, 102L, 103L, 104L, 105L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 
8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 
21L, 22L, 23L, 24L, 25L, 26L, 27L, 28L, 29L, 30L, 31L, 32L, 33L, 
34L, 35L, 36L, 37L, 38L, 39L, 40L, 41L, 42L, 43L, 44L, 45L, 46L, 
47L, 48L, 49L, 50L, 51L, 52L, 53L, 54L, 55L, 56L, 57L, 58L, 59L, 
60L, 61L, 62L, 63L, 64L, 65L, 66L, 67L, 68L, 69L, 70L, 71L, 72L, 
73L, 74L, 75L, 76L, 77L, 78L, 79L, 80L, 81L, 82L, 83L, 84L, 85L, 
86L, 87L, 88L, 89L, 90L, 91L, 92L, 93L, 94L, 95L, 96L, 97L, 98L, 
99L, 100L, 101L, 102L, 103L, 104L, 105L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 
6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 
19L, 20L, 21L, 22L, 23L, 24L, 25L, 26L, 27L, 28L, 29L, 30L, 31L, 
32L, 33L, 34L, 35L, 36L, 37L, 38L, 39L, 40L, 41L, 42L, 43L, 44L, 
45L, 46L, 47L, 48L, 49L, 50L, 51L, 52L, 53L, 54L, 55L, 56L, 57L, 
58L, 59L, 60L, 61L, 62L, 63L, 64L, 65L, 66L, 67L, 68L, 69L, 70L, 
71L, 72L, 73L, 74L, 75L, 76L, 77L, 78L, 79L, 80L, 81L, 82L, 83L, 
84L, 85L, 86L, 87L, 88L, 89L, 90L, 91L, 92L, 93L, 94L, 95L, 96L, 
97L, 98L, 99L, 100L, 101L, 102L, 103L, 104L, 105L), medical_any_lib = c(TRUE, 
TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, 
TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, 
TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, 
TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, 
TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, 
TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, 
TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, 
TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, 
TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, 
TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, 
TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, 
TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, 
TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, 
TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, 
TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, 
TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, 
TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, 
TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, 
TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, 
FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, 
FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, 
FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, 
FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, 
FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, 
FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, 
FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, 
FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, 
FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, 
FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, 
FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, 
FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE), medical_any_res = c(FALSE, 
FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, 
FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, 
FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, 
FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, 
FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, 
FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, 
FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, 
FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, 
FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, 
FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, 
FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, 
FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, 
FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, 
FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, 
FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, 
FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, 
FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, 
FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, 
FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, 
FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, 
FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, 
FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, 
FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, 
FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, 
TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, 
TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, 
TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, 
TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, 
TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, 
TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, 
TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, 
TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, 
TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE)), row.names = c(NA, 
-315L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

And here the operation I am running

```
data %>% 
  group_by(ccode,week) %>% 
  summarise(
    facilitations = sum(medical_any_lib, na.rm = T),
    restrictions = sum(medical_any_res, na.tm = T) 
    )
```

Comment: `restrictions = sum(medical_any_res, na.rm = T)` not `na.tm = T`

Comment: Thank's @Ali. I burned my eyes on the code (is actually longer than that) and never realized that in some random places I wrote na.tm. Good eyesight!

Comment: just copy this: `data %>% 
  group_by(ccode, week) %>% 
  summarise(facilitations = sum(medical_any_lib, na.rm = T),
            restrictions = sum(medical_any_res, na.rm = T))`

Answer (score 0):

The solution, as @Ali wrote in the comments, simply lied in the `na.tm = T` option, that of course is wrong.
Strange enough, my RStudio does not flag the error.